# Using shell_exec()

Tags: php, shell-exec, minecraft

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could use `shell_exec()` properly. I have enabled it in the `php.ini` file but it doesn't seem to work.

Do I have to log into the shell using a username and password?

How would I access something that is on screen -r through `shell_exec()`?

P.S. I'm trying to run the list command on a Minecraft Server and return the data.

Comment: Are you running the php script as an executable, or is apache running it through the browser?

Comment: Apache through the browser. I'm not running an .sh file.

Comment: you can run a php file as an executable.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to log into the shell, the shell will execute as the OS user executing your php commands. To begin, first test that you have shell_exec working properly:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Okay, that worked. It gave me an output of the files. I need to get to the minecraft server, through the shell in PHP though... No idea how to do that.

I've been using screen -r in the command line using PuTTy but I don't know whether or not that applies here.

Comment: When I use screen -r rather than ls -lart I get this error: Must be connected to a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `shell_exec` with interactive commands. Since you are using screen simply enable the screen log and use file functions to read the `screenlog.0` file created in the folder from where the screen was started.

Comment: Could you please expand.. I have no idea what you're talking about. Sorry I'm a bit of a newbie.